# MySQL/MariaDB (innoDB)のアカウント管理仕様(作成/更新日,有効/無効 等)について教えてください。

Tags: mysql, mariadb

RCM項目で データベースアカウントの取り扱いについて 作成日 更新日 有効 無効 が管理されているかを求められています。
長らく Oracle Database を採用しているため DBA_USERS などの項目がイメージされていると思われます。

しかしMySQL/MariaDB (innoDB)にはそのような項目が見受けられません。
mysql.user などmysql.*のtableでは見受けられませんでした。
アカウントのログイン管理として「どこからのアクセス(Host項目)→アカウント→パスワード」となっているのは把握しているつもりですが、上記の作成日などの管理がどのようになっているのか。
MySQL、MariaDBの公式ドキュメントを見てもその辺りの記述を見つけることができませんでした。
"仕様です"で頷いてくれる筈もなく、なんとか裏付けとなる資料を探しています。

ご存じの方、または「こう説明すれば納得してもらえる」がある方。
ご教授下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 5.7 以降であれば「アカウントのロック」は利用できるようです。

[MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 6.2.15 Account Locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-locking.html)

作成日や更新日については既にご自身でも調べられた通り、MySQL(MariaDB)では管理されていなさそうです (セキュリティ関連という事ならパスワードの有効期限はありました)。

"仕様です" で納得されるかどうかは、「Oracle と MySQL とは違う製品だから」としか言いようがない気がします。

Comment: 台帳管理としました。